# TypeORM: how to .find() exact match?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm writing a TypeORM resolver to delete an entity with the following code:

- Book schema in the database:  `id | idInAPI | userId`
- user is the other end of a many to one relation
- Delete book query arguments are idInAPI and the context (to get the user).

---

```
const { userId } = req.session; // current user taken from cookie
    
const book= await Book.findOneOrFail({ where: [{ user: userId }, { idInAPI: bookId }] });
const response = await Book.delete(book.id);
```

The code does delete a book in my database, but my problem is that `.find()` looks for approximate values and not the exact one, so if I try to delete the book with id 12, the book with id 1234 might get deleted.

How can I force find to look for the exact match for user and book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by passing the arguments directly to `.delete()` with the following syntax:

```
const response = await Book.delete({ idInAPI: bookId, user: { id: userId } });
```

Answer (score 2):

the issue is that you are using `findOneOrFail` method. You should use `find()` method this will search for the exact match

Comment: It seems to be the same. If I try to delete the game with id 1, it returns all the games with a 1 the id (123, 133, 143...). I imagine the same is happening with the user.

I am trying to delete the book with the unique user_id - book_id tuple (books and users on their own can be repeated).